# Angular2 Subscription always comes up null

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I have what I thought was a fairly simple setup. I am creating a user profile in a profile-input component. Then After the form is submitted and the user created, I want to send the user to a profile-img-upload component to add a photo. My understanding is that this would make sense to be done through saving the created profile into a profile service, and then calling that profile in the img-upload component. But I'm missing something because when I get to the img-upload component **console.log(this.profile)** the profile is always null.

I feel like I'm misunderstanding something very core to subscriptions and observables here. All I want to do is create a Profile object on the first component, and then pass the created Profile to the 2nd component to then be able to upload a photo and assign it to the Profile.

Can someone please help me understand what I'm missing here?

**profile-input.component**

```
import...

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-profile-input',
  templateUrl: 'profile-input.template.html',
  directives: [REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES]
 })

export class ProfileInputComponent implements OnInit {
 @Output() profile: Profile;
 profile: Profile = null;

constructor(private formBuilder:FormBuilder,
            private profileSrevice: ProfileService,
            private errorService: ErrorService,
            private router: Router,
            private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

 onSubmit() {
 const profile: Profile = new Profile(
            this.profileForm.value.first_name,
            this.profileForm.value.last_name  
 );

 this.profileSrevice.addProfile(profile)
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    console.log('what comes back from addProfile is: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
                    this.profileSrevice.profiles.push(data);

                    // The line below will superceded the one above.
                    this.profileSrevice.pushData(data);
                },
                error => this.errorService.handleError(error)
            );
        this.router.navigate(['profile-img-upload', {myProfile: this.profile}]);
 }
```

**profile.service.ts**

```
 import...

 @Injectable()
 export class ProfileService {
    pushedData = new EventEmitter<Profile>();

    pushData(value: Profile) {
     this.pushedData.emit(value);
     console.log('value in service is ');
     console.log(value);
    }
 }
```

**profile-img-upload.component.ts**

```
import...

@Component({
 moduleId: module.id,
 selector: 'my-profile-img-upload',
 templateUrl: 'profile-img-upload.template.html',
 directives: [ ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTIVES, NgClass, NgStyle, CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES ],
 providers: [AWSUploadService, UploadFileService]
})

export class ProfileImgUploadComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() myProfile: Profile;
  profile: Profile;

  constructor(private uploadFileService: UploadFileService,
            private route: ActivatedRoute,
            private profileService: ProfileService,
            private errorService: ErrorService) {
    this.filesToUpload = [];}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.profileService.pushedData.subscribe(
        (value: Profile) => this.profile
    );

    console.log("this.profile in img upload is");
    console.log(this.profile);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I was having was due to a a misunderstanding of how to use observables. I was redirecting to a different page (reloading a new template with a new component) to get from the profile data to the area where I wanted to upload the images. This was a flawed concept. The way I fixed it was to do the following:

1. Remove the 2nd component and template for the upload and incorporate all of that code into the profile creation component
2. Add some ngIf statements to determine when to show different areas of the profile creation page based on the user accomplishing different tasks, (i.e. entering profile info and creating a profile object, adding a photo, adding a video).

By doing these things I was always on the same page so I could reference the results of 1 action to use in another, and as things were accomplished I could set variables to control the state of the application and what was being shown to the user.

The final code for the template is below:

```
<script src="profile-input.component.ts"></script>
<section class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
  <form [hidden]="formSubmitted" [formGroup]="profileForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="first_name"
            class="form-control"
            formControlName="first_name">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="last_name">Last name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="last_name"
            class="form-control"
            formControlName="last_name">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
      <label>UserType</label>
      <input type="checkbox"  id="producer" class="form-control" formControlName="producer" >Producer<br>
      <input type="checkbox"  id="client"   class="form-control" formControlName="client" >Client<br>
      <input type="checkbox"  id="creative" class="form-control" formControlName="creative" >Creative<br>
    </div>


    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!profileForm.valid" >{{ !profile ? 'Add Profile' : 'Save Profile' }}</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="onCancel()" *ngIf="profile">Cancel</button>
  </form>
</section>

<!-- image upload START-->
<section [hidden]="!imgUploadVisible" class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
  <h2 *ngIf="createdProfile">Welcome {{createdProfile.first_name}}!</h2>
  <p>Now lets get a look at you.</p>
  <hr>
  <h2>Profile Image Upload</h2>
  <input type="file" (change)="imgFileChangeEvent($event)" placeholder="Upload file..." />
  <br>
  <button type="button" (click)="uploadImg()">Upload Image</button>
  <hr>

  <div *ngIf="uploadFile" >
    Uploaded File Path: {{ uploadFile }}
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="img" *ngIf="uploadFile">
        <img [src]="uploadFile" width="200px" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <button [hidden]="!uploadFile" type="button" (click)="sendToS3()">Send TO S3</button>
  <hr>
  <div *ngIf="s3LocString">
    S3 Location: {{s3LocString}}
    <br>
    <img [src]="s3LocString" width="200px" alt="">
  </div>

  <button type="button" (click)="imgUploadComplete()">Next</button>

</section>
<!-- image upload END-->


<!-- Video upload START-->

<section [hidden]="!vidUploadVisible" class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
  <h2>Upload Profile Video</h2>
  <p>Now show us what you can do.</p>
  <hr>
  <h2>Demo Video Upload</h2>
  <input type="file" (change)="vidFileChangeEvent($event)" placeholder="Upload file..." />
  <br>
  <button type="button" (click)="uploadVid()">Upload Video</button>
  <hr>

  <div *ngIf="vidUploadFile" >
    Uploaded File Path: {{ vidUploadFile }}
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="vid" *ngIf="vidUploadFile">
        <video autoplay controls [src]="vidUploadFile"></video>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</section>
```

The important parts of the profile-input component is below:

```
  uploadImg() {
    console.log('this.createdProfile before upload');
    console.log(this.createdProfile);
    this.uploadFileService.makeFileRequest("http://localhost:3000/upload", this.createdProfile.profileId, this.imgFilesToUpload, 'profileImg')
      .subscribe(
        (result) => {
          console.log('result in prof input action removed is');
          console.log(result);
           this.imageUploaded = true;
           this.formSubmitted = true;
           this.uploadFile = result.obj.path;
           this.uploadObject = result.obj
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log('We are in error');
          console.error(error);
        });
  }

  uploadVid() {
    console.log('this.createdProfile before upload');
    console.log(this.createdProfile);
    this.uploadFileService.makeFileRequest("http://localhost:3000/upload", this.createdProfile.profileId, this.vidFilesToUpload, 'profileVideo')
      .subscribe(
        (result) => {
          console.log('result in prof input action removed is');
          console.log(result);
          this.vidUploaded = true;
          this.vidUploadFile = result.obj.path;
          this.vidUploadObject = result.obj
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log('We are in error');
          console.error(error);
        });
  }

  sendToS3() {
    console.log('uploading to S3');
    console.log(this.uploadObject);

    this.uploadFileService.sendToS3(this.uploadObject, this.createdProfile.profileId, this.uploadObject._id)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log(data);
          this.s3Location = data;
          this.s3LocString = data.Location;
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  }
```

Hope this helps someone else to understand these concepts better.

Answer (score 0):

You have to move code that references data returned from a subscription into the subscription callback. This callback is called when the data arrives from the observable

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.profileService.pushedData.subscribe(
        (value: Profile) => {
            this.profile = value;
            console.log("this.profile in img upload is");
            console.log(this.profile);
        });
     }
 }
```

Comment: I tried this, when I do, I actually never see the log get to the console saying "this.profile in img upload is"

Comment: The last output that gets to the console is the **value in service is** and then Profile object (coming from the profile.service pushData method)

Comment: Hard to get from a few code snippets what's actually going on at runtime. You need to be aware that the data only is available after the callback gets called.

Comment: Actually I think this helped me understand something. I dont know that this actually should be an observable. What I'm trying to do is create a Profile in the first component and then pass that info to the second component. But, the 2nd component doesnt exist until after the 1st component is done, which is why the observable is not working. So the question is, whats the right way to pass an object from 1 component to another. (I thought this was supposed to be done by storing the data to be shared within the service somehow).

Comment: Sorry, too tired to investigate more closely. Maybe you want to use a `BehaviorSubject` that emits the last value to new subscribers. For normal `Observables` it can easily happen that the value is emitted before the component got a chance to subscribe and then the value is lost. Time for bed .... chrrr, chrrr ;-)